# adding email button with report to customer in openerp

Tags: email, button, report, odoo, openerp-7

i want to add in openerp7 under customer the an button which is able to send e-mails with attached reports.

i added this code under form view

```
<header>
      <button name="email_send" string="Anschreiben zum drucken verschicken" type="object"      class="oe_highlight" groups="base.group_user"/>
</header>
```

But when i press the button it always show up this error:

```
TypeError: email_send() takes at least 7 arguments (5 given)
```

Does anyone know how to handle this?

---

this was too long for edit so i made an answer don´t wonder.

Now i´m using _email_send and this is the error message i get:

```
Client Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/openerp/htdocs/openerp/addons/web/http.py", line 204, in dispatch
  response["result"] = method(self, **self.params)
File "/opt/openerp/htdocs/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1132, in call_button
  action = self._call_kw(req, model, method, args, {})
File "/opt/openerp/htdocs/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1120, in _call_kw
  return getattr(req.session.model(model), method)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/openerp/htdocs/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 42, in proxy
  result = self.proxy.execute_kw(self.session._db, self.session._uid, self.session._password,                  self.model, method, args, kw)
File "/opt/openerp/htdocs/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 30, in proxy_method
  result = self.session.send(self.service_name, method, *args)
File "/opt/openerp/htdocs/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 103, in send
  raise xmlrpclib.Fault(openerp.tools.ustr(e), formatted_info)


Server Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/openerp/htdocs/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 89, in send
  return openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service_name, method, args)
File "/opt/openerp/htdocs/openerp/netsvc.py", line 292, in dispatch_rpc
  result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
File "/opt/openerp/htdocs/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 626, in dispatch
  res = fn(db, uid, *params)
File "/opt/openerp/htdocs/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 190, in execute_kw
  return self.execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})
File "/opt/openerp/htdocs/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 132, in wrapper
  return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/openerp/htdocs/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 199, in execute
  res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
File "/opt/openerp/htdocs/openerp/addons/audittrail/audittrail.py", line 522, in execute_cr
  return fct_src(cr, uid, model, method, *args, **kw)
File "/opt/openerp/htdocs/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 187, in execute_cr
  return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
TypeError: email_send() takes at least 7 arguments (5 given)
```

Is there any information more you need? thanks in advance

Comment: Now i´m using the _email_send

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you to achieve the desired functionality. Try it out.

If you want to send an HTML email, the only way I have found is to send an email template via a server action.

Once you have the template created, discover it's template id by viewing the template and seeing what the id parameter is in the url.

Then create a new server action, set the object to match the template and set the type to python code. Insert the following code:

self.pool.get('email.template').send_mail(cr, uid, , context['active_id'],True, context=context)

Replacing  with the appropriate template id.

Just explaining some of the other fields

```
context['active_id'] gives the current id of the lead/invoice/etc being used to create the template with
The 5th valueTrue forces the email to be sent immediately rather than adding it to the queue. It would be better to leave as False but due to a bug in version 7, it can lose email addresses when being added to the queue.
```

You can look in addons/email_template/email_template.py and search for the send_mail function for further information.

Comment: And if its the email send function in res.partner that you intend to call, then use _email_send instead because the email_send function is called from within that function. And please provide more details regarding the required functionality for clarity.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Hi gerald....yes I know...but as per the information he provided...this was the best answer i could provide and i dnt have sufficient reputation to comment...thats why i answered and then seeked for clarification.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers. If it happens, don't worry. Keep this up and you'll earn reputation soon enough.